# Android - About box in application manager?

Tags: java, android, about-box, application-management

I was wondering does anyone know how to give an Android application an about box in the application manager?

So when a user goes to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications and clicks on an app there is an About box there that the user can click and info about the app pops up.

Like the images below?

[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1638/about1l.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1638/about1l.png)

[alt text http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/250/about2r.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/250/about2r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an HTC rom only feature and you can't create it for your own applications.

Unless it's new in 2.x then I didn't even know it's there.

Comment: Nope it's something HTC seems to have added.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking that, its a good idea, maybe something for the next update?

Comment: I think so too. It's nice to be able to show you applications/company's information in a centralized place.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can recommend this officially for the next Android release?